# Jquery slide effect in ASP.NET Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I have a question is there a way I could create the collapsible effect with the Jquery show(), hide(), slide(). Functions and has anyone found any examples to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the gridview is just rendered as a table in html, you should be able to use the jquery effects on that table.

if your gridview had an `ID="GridView1"` then the selector would be:

```
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>')
```

then you could have in javascript things like:

```
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').slideUp();
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').slideDown();
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').show();
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').hide();
```